# GCP service account - access denied for NodeJS script

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-iam

Hello I am getting desperate.

I am trying to import data into Google BigQuery, using Cron and NodeJS script. But I am getting access denied error:

```
Access Denied: Dataset arcane-pillar-XXX:MyProj: User does not have bigquery.datasets.get permission for dataset arcane-pillar-XXX:MyProj
```

1. I've created a service account bq-data-import-user@arcane-pillar-XXX.iam.gserviceaccount.com
2. I've created a key, downloaded it as a JSON file and set the environment variable
3. When I run my NodeJS script on my local machine I get the error.
4. I've tested the account with Policy Troubleshooter. The Troubleshooter says that the permission is granted.

I've tried to recreate the account many times but nothing have helped. I've verified that there is no project mismatch, because the error changes when I delete the dataset.

Any tips?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
"use strict";

const {BigQuery} = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');

process.env["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "/etc/my-app/google-application-credentials.json";


const bq = new BigQuery();
const bqDataset = (await bq.dataset("TheDataset").get({ autoCreate: true }))[0]; // THIS LINE THROWS THE ERROR
const bqTable = (await bqDataset.table("TheTable").get({ autoCreate: true, schema: [ /* The BQ schema */ ] }))[0];

for await (const row of rows) { // Rows is a async generator (cursor in MySQL)
    await bqTable.insert(row);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is our public [article](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started) shows the recommended way to authenticate to a Cloud API.

Based on our public [document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/authentication/service-account-file), create credentials in your application from the service account file. Then use the credentials to create a service object with the BigQuery Client Libraries.

```
// Create a BigQuery client explicitly using service account credentials.
// by specifying the private key file.

const {BigQuery} = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');

const options = {
  keyFilename: 'path/to/service_account.json',
  projectId: 'my_project',
};

const bigquery = new BigQuery(options);
```

Comment: Definitely an improvement, but I guess this wouldn't have helped. The code actually works as is, but I needed to fill the third step of the service account creation wizard. This have solved my issue.